# setup.py files equivalence of data-files attribute in pyproject.toml

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

Does anyone know the equivalent syntax of data-files in pyptoject.toml. I know that it's deprecated but I wanted to do something quick and dirty without making too many changes to an existing repo.

I am aware that [tools.setuptools] works with script-files and data-files directives but I have been struggling to get data-files to work although I was successful with scriipt-files. I have tried and a few other combinations but setuptools always throws an absolute fit:

```
[tool.setuptools]
data-files = [
    { "etc":  [
         "etc/foo.json", 
         "etc/foo2.json"
       ]
    }
]
script-files = [
    "scripts/foo_scripts.py"
]
```

Note there is an etc directory in the base directory of the repo that I am working with.

Comment: I would guess that it is not supported in `pyproject.toml`. Why not use a `setup.cfg` or `setup.py` for these settings?

Comment: Trying to consolidate to a single pyproject.toml file. script-files is also deprecated but still works. I thought that data-files would work the same way as it too is only deprecated. Looks like I may be out of luck though. I may just have to bite the bullet and re-arrange my repo in the day that pyproject.toml prefers.

Comment: According to [this](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html#setuptools-specific-configuration) `data-files` seem supported in `pyproject.toml`. But it is not clear how to format the value for the `data-files` key. Maybe you need to try different combinations or look it up online more deeply, there might be example somewhere.

Comment: Believe you me, I have been searching like a fiend and hence my turning to StackOverflow but I will try some other resources to get satisfaction.

Comment: Maybe this example in setuptools test suite: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/d42e248710a0d7ea9920c92fe3515d4ec3298176/setuptools/tests/config/test_pyprojecttoml.py#L74

Comment: Thanks for this sinoroc. I think that this github code snippet was the key! I had not considered the angle of looking at the setuptools source code! This is definitely not a piece of configuration that seems to be widely used anymore and hence my difficulty finding examples via Google. The format in the example worked like a champ though. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Good that you found a solution. I recommend you write your own answer containing this solution and accept it.

Comment: I was trying to do this yesterday but then forgot that your answers were not posted as replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sinoroc's comment that pointed me to this link: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/d42e248710a0d7ea9920c92fe3515d4ec3298176/setuptools/tests/config/test_pyprojecttoml.py#L74 was the key to solving my issue. That link provides an example of how to translate the data-files attribute of setup.py and setuptools into something that can be used in pyproject.toml.

This is definitely not information that's widely disseminated.

```ini
[tool.setuptools.data-files]
"data" = ["_files/*.txt"]
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @MadMax This is quite a poor quality answer. I added the actual example in the answer to salvage this a bit. The example is the most important bit, but somehow you avoided adding it. I recommend you check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer "_Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible._"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback sinoroc. This was not immediately apparent to me as I was only focused on the link, how it helped me and the convenience it provided.

Nevertheless, the point about links going stale is a good one. I will keep that in the mind for any future answers I might create. 

This was also my first Stack Overflow answer.